# Pommbundle Custom query Insert or update - Symfony2

Tags: postgresql, symfony, pomm

I would like to create a custom insert or update with pommbundle but in the documentation i have just for a select query.

It's possible to give me a simple example with a possibility to have a last insert id? with ... currval ou lastval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of inserting data in the database using PommBundle.

If you do not use the Model Manager and you want to perform a custom insertion:

```
// in the controller
$this->get('pomm')
    ->getDefaultSession()
    ->getQueryManager()
    ->query('INSERT INTO … VALUES ($*::text, $*::int4…)', [$param1, $param2]);
```

This method is tedious because you have to specify all the fields by hand, it may break if the schema changes but you can specify a complex insertion query using SQL acrobatics.

If the goal is just to save a model, the model manager eases the insertion of data using entities:

```
use Path\To\Model\MyDb\MySchema\MyEntityModel;

// …
$entity = $this->get('pomm')
    ->getDefaultSession()
    ->getModel(MyEntityModel::class)
    ->createAndSave(['field1' => $param1, …]);
```

The returned entity is the image of the inserted data with the database default values (most of the time auto generated primary key).

Here is [the documentation](https://github.com/pomm-project/ModelManager/blob/2.0/documentation/model_manager.rst#createandsave) about it.

Comment: Work fine if i use "getModel" and not "getModelManager" in symfony

Comment: Thx, typo fixed.